# Spark streaming with broadcast joins

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, broadcast

I have a spark streaming use case where I plan to keep a dataset broadcasted and cached on each executor. Every micro batch in streaming will create a dataframe out of the RDD and join the batch. My test code given below will perform the broadcast operation for each batch. Is there a way to broadcast it just once?

```
val testDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .schema(schema).load("file:///shared/data/test-data.txt") 

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("DevNode", 9999)

lines.foreachRDD((rdd, timestamp) => {
    val recordDF = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(l => Record(l(0).toInt, l(1))).toDF()
    val resultDF = recordDF.join(broadcast(testDF), "Age")
    resultDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("file:///shared/data/output/streaming/"+timestamp)
    }
```

For every batch this file was read and broadcast was performed.

```
16/02/18 12:24:02 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/shared/data/test-data.txt:27+28
16/02/18 12:24:02 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/shared/data/test-data.txt:0+27

16/02/18 12:25:00 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/shared/data/test-data.txt:27+28
16/02/18 12:25:00 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/shared/data/test-data.txt:0+27
```

Any suggestion on broadcast dataset only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for now broadcasted tables are not reused. See: [SPARK-3863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3863)

Perform broadcasting outside `foreachRDD` loop:

```
val testDF = broadcast(sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
 .schema(schema).load(...))

lines.foreachRDD((rdd, timestamp) => { 
  val recordDF = ???
  val resultDF = recordDF.join(testDF, "Age")
  resultDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(...)
}
```

Comment: I had tried that approach too and it doesn't broadcast as expected. Probably because foreachRDD is executed in driver's context. BTW, we have to use testDF.value in join statement. I assume it was a typo.

Comment: Thanks! 

On a side note, will sc.broadcast(someDataFrame) bring data to driver before broadcast or will it do a bittorrent style broadcast from each executor? I always used broadcast hint with SQL. Wonder what is the difference.

Comment: This won't work. I mean you can broadcast a `DataFrame` (it is `Serializable` after all) but you cannot nest operations on DDS. You could simply collect, transform to something more useful than an `Array[Row]` and broadcast local data structure. Then simply use UDFs.